# Aspectj advice order

Tags: spring, aspectj

I'm using spring `@Transctional` with **aspectj mode** and **load time weaving**.

My aspect uses a point cut that matches annotation `@MyAnnotation`

```
@Aspect
@Configurable
public class MyAspect{
 ....
    @Around("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(annotation)")
    public Object around( ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, MyAnnotation annotation ) throws Throwable {
        ...
    }
}
```

,and is declared in **aop.xml**:

```
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <include within="mypackage..*"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="mypackage.MyAspect" />
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

My usage:

```
    @Transactional
    @MyAnnotation
    private void method() {
      ...
    }
```

How can I order the aspect invocation order so that the `Transactional` aspect is called before `MyAspect`?

I need it to first create a transaction then call my aspect logic inside that transaction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by adding [@DeclarePrecedence](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/adk15notebook/ataspectj-declare.html) to aspect:

```
@Aspect
@DeclarePrecedence("org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.*,*")
@Configurable
public class MyAspect
```

The spring aspect which handles `@Transactional` is `org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect`, but to be on the safe side for future renames I used `org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.*`.